# Firebase Crashlytics not showing crash reports even though it has crashes

Tags: firebase, crashlytics

We have a project where we use Firebase Crashlytics to collect crash reports from our iOS and Android app. Currently, the console is not showing any crash reports. Initially we assumed something was wrong with our project setup, but today I discovered that Crashlytics actually has been receiving the crash data, since I can see it on the Project Overview page:
[image]

However, when I open the Crashlytics page it is empty (it only shown me the guide on how to integrate Crashlytics in your app):
[image]

This is the case for both out iOS and Android app. We also have another project that is set up in the same way, but here the reports are shown correctly.

Is there perhaps some console configuration we are missing?

Comment: Crash Free Users is collected by the Analytics SDK, something could be blocking Crashlytics from sending the actual crash report. The best way to know what Crashlytics is doing is to enable debug logging and cause a test crash: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation?platform=ios

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, in logs it was sending reports to Firebase Crashlytics but in firebase it did not appear, after wasting 2 days I contacted their support and send them my console logs. **They told me to re download your GoogleServices-Info file and replace it in your project.**

After replacing my newly downloaded file, Crashlytics in firebase showed up.
Even both files were same but replacing solved the issue.

Here is how you can [enable your debug logs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation?platform=ios#enable-debug-logging).