# Firebase Crashlytics not showing crash reports

Tags: java, android, firebase, crashlytics, app-quality-insights

I am using Firebase Crashlytics whereas I can't see my crashes on both App Quality Insight and Firebase Console.

Initially it displayed "Currently logged in user has no permission on this project"Later i resolved that and now its showing "You don't have any issues yet", Even though the Crash occurs.

NPE is showing on logcat but not on App Quality Insight.

Anyone faced the same?

I tried Changing my Package Name and Registering in Firebase Console.Cleaned and Rebuilt Project n time but no use.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70006956/firebase-crashlytics-not-showing-crash-reports-even-though-it-has-crashes?rq=2) help?

Comment: You can try to add `<meta-data android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled" android:value="true" />` to your manifest or just call from your code `FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true)`.

Comment: @Boken  
This really helped..Thanks

Comment: Added as answer

Answer (score 0):

You can add to manifest:

```
<meta-data android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled" android:value="true" />
```

or just call from your code

```
FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true)
```